# java JPanel How to fixed sizes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to have a resizable panel, that always has the top green panel of a fixed depth. i.e. all changes in height should effect the yellow panel only.

My code below is almost OK, except the green panel varies in size a little.

How do I do this?

```
            Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Panel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        JPanel TopPanel = new JPanel();
        TopPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,150));
        TopPanel.setVisible(true);
        TopPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
        MainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,750));
        MainPanel.setVisible(true);
        MainPanel.setOpaque(true);
        MainPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        Panel.add(TopPanel);
        Panel.add(MainPanel);
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question didn't restrict the solution to a `BoxLayout`, so I am going to suggest a different layout manager.

I would attack this with a `BorderLayout` and put the green panel in the PAGE_START location.  Then put the yellow panel in the CENTER location without a `preferredSize` call.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Here is an SSCCE example of the solution:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPad extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel green = new JPanel();
        green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 150));
        green.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel yellow = new JPanel();
        yellow.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        frame.getContentPane().add(green, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.getContentPane().add(yellow, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: See comment for gla3dr

Comment: @ManInMoon, works fine for me, I have edited by answer with a full example.  There must be something different you are doing.

Comment: +1. This helped me fix an issue where I originally had 3 components in a VerticalBox and a change to one would cause all 3 to change size. Now, changes to one don't affect the size of others due to using a BorderLayout.

Answer (score 3):

If you make your `Panel` use `BorderLayout` instead of `BoxLayout` and put `TopPanel` in `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `MainPanel` in `BorderLayout.CENTER`, then they will both resize horizontally, but only the `MainPanel` will resize vertically.

See the [BorderLayout documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)

Comment: That doesn't appear correct, green and yellow panels remain the same height RELATIVE to each other, BUT green does grow and shrink - I was hoping to fix its height